# How to grep whatever is there between "CommonName....Flow:" using TCL regexp?

Tags: tcl, expect

```
set line {
Aug 07 18:12:00 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.daily

motion.com. Flow: 0x87078500.
Aug 07 18:12:00 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName DigiCer

t High Assurance CA-3. Flow: 0x87078500.
}


if {![regexp {CommonName ([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*) Flow:} $line junk one]} {
error "invalid parsing"
}
puts "$one"
```

How to grep whatever is there between "CommonName....Flow:". I have written above script. but its not working. I am unable to handle a space that is there between "*.daily and motion" in $line variable.

output should be:

*.dailymotion.com.

DigiCert High Assurance CA-3.

Please help me with your ideas.

Thanks,

Balu P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.` which is a wildcard to match any characters, except you should make it lazy by adding a `?`:

```
[regexp {CommonName (.*?) Flow:} $line - one]
```

Except now, your lines are split into multiple lines, so you might want to replace newlines:

```
regsub -all {[\r\n]} $one "" one
```

Will give you the variable `$one` without newlines.

---

```
set line {
    Aug 07 18:12:00 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName *.daily

    motion.com. Flow: 0x87078500.
    Aug 07 18:12:00 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized Server Cert CommonName DigiCer

    t High Assurance CA-3. Flow: 0x87078500.
}


if {![regexp {CommonName (.*?) Flow:} $line - one]} {
    error "invalid parsing"
}
regsub -all {[\r\n]} $one "" one
puts "$one"
```